# cv.bitwise_and, error: (-209:Sizes do not match) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type)

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory

error: OpenCV(4.6.0) /io/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:212:

> error: (-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match) The operation is
> neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type),
> nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function 'binary_op'

[image]

```
img1 = cv2.resize(smooth2, (960, 540))
img2 = cv2.resize(edges, (960, 540))

cartoonImage = cv2.bitwise_and(img1, img2)
ReSized6 = cv2.resize(cartoonImage, (960, 540))
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. Please share two sample images! Also please `print` the `shape` of both images and share it with us!

Comment: I had a similar issue (the two arrays had the same size and the two variables were of the same type). I fixed using `image_masked = cv2.bitwise_or(np.array(Image_A, dtype = np.uint16), np.array(Image_B,  dtype = np.uint16))`.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is perhaps with the type of single element inside the numpy array, it happened to before but I discovered that one of the 2 images was array of `<class 'numpy.uint8'>` and the other was array of `<class 'numpy.uint32'>` so what I did is that I converted from `uint32` to `uint8` by using the function called `astype()`, so assume the image to be converted is called `img` the what I did is:

```
img = img.astype(np.uint8)
```

and you can know the type of the 1 element using the function called `type()` so for the matrix called `img` which is 3-dimensional in my case, you can write:

```
print(type(img[0][0][0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the error message is kind of misleading. The two images must have the same `shape`. You have to convert at least one of them. I can reproduce the error message if I use a `bgr` and a `grayscale` image. So please check the shape of `smooth2` and `edges`!

Comment: I don't think shape is an issue here. Its most probably the data type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

the main problem was that we need to make sure that the input images data in unsigned 8 bit format.
and to convert them we can use

'my_image = cv.cvtColor(my_image, cv.CV_8U)'